# Losing contents of my dataframe when converting to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

So, I am trying to obtain information and manipulate my columns 'Lyrics' column into 3 new columns by storing the 'Song' and 'Lyrics' columns into a dictionary. From there I am trying to take the value('Lyrics') and add the information back into a new column on my df. I'm just trying to figure out where I went wrong because once I convert my two columns into a dictionary, my length is telling me I only have 783 when the length of the original content is 798.

```
data = pd.read_csv('small_lyrics.csv', names=['Song', 'Year released', 'Artist', 'Genre', 'Lyrics'])
cntry = len([w for w in data['Genre'] if re.match(r'Country', w)])
jazz = len([w for w in data['Genre'] if re.match(r'Jazz', w)])

print(f'Jazz: {jazz} \nCountry: {cntry}')

len(data.set_index('Song').to_dict()['Lyrics'])


output is:
Jazz: 429 
Country: 369
783
```

Comment: Have you located the differences? pandas.DataFrame.diff might help.

Comment: No, that's not quite what I'm looking for. I'm missing data from the data frame. Not trying to calculate the difference but locate the missing elements when converted to a dictionary.

Comment: I figured it out. In the file that I have, there are multiple songs with the same name title so the dictionary only took the unique song titles which is why there were missing elements.